# PHP - php file return blank page (VM - Ubuntu)

Tags: php, linux

I have a problem, my local server (VM - Ubuntu) can't read php file.

The return result is a blank page

the php code:

```
<?php

echo "here";

?>
```

**PS:** if I create the file on Linux by command line it's work without any problem if I created from windows by shared file, it doesn't work.

is there any solution to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you check the error logs. You are not giving us much to go on here information wize

Comment: Did you try wrapping some HTML around the echo

Comment: try this sudo a2enmod php7  sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: @RiggsFolly if the extension of the file is php or phtml, nothing work

Comment: Are you doing this using the CLI or via a web server

Comment: Do you have a web server installed on your machine? Check if the correct ports are forwarded.

Comment: @BramVerstraten it's a VM, using Ubuntu like OS

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand your question exactly sir, I use a VM like server, and I lunch to the website by IP of the machine.

Comment: I understand it's a VM, but you need to have a web server installed on your Ubuntu OS. For example **Apache** or **nginx**.